# How to enable editing mode animated for a single UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview

A `UITableView` is in editing mode. Each cell has a `UISwitch`. The delegate method `tableView(_ tableView:canEditRowAt:)` returns `true` only for cells where the switch is on.

When a switch value changes to `on` the cell should become editable, when it changes to `off` it should become non-editable.

I tried to change the cell's editing mode by setting `isEditing=false`. But unless I call `tableView.reloadData()` the cell's editing mode does not change. However when I reload the data immediately after the switch value changes, the switch animation is not visible.

Calling `tableView.reloadRows` on the cell also breaks the switch animation.

How can a single `UITableViewCell` be enabled / disabled for editing while preserving the switch animation in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: you have SwitchTableViewCell and ViewController that is delegate to your cells, and handles changes in the Switches' values. In the delegate method, lets say `didChangeSwitchValue(at indexPath: IndexPath, newValue: Bool)`, you need to update your model and then call the following line to update the tableView layout, without breaking the switch animation.

Assuming that edit style is for deletion the following line fixed the animation:

```
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
```

Note that, I have tried with `UITableViewRowAnimation.none` and with `tableView.reloadData()` and as you say the animation breaks, but with animation option `UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic` it looks fine. Please update your question if you have any issues with other editing mode.

Comment: The animation does not work any different, `.automatic` is the same as `.fade`, it fades out the switch and fades in another switch with the new value. That is not the same smooth animation as when table view goes into editing mode where the handle slides in on the right side.